# class return object location instead of the value

Tags: python, class, return

I have used a class for a program I have been working on. Unfortunately, I am struggling to return the value instead of the object memory location.

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data 

class BinaryTree:
    root = None  
    @classmethod
    def InsertNode(cls, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if cls.root == None:
            cls.root = newNode
            return cls.root
        else: 
            queue = []
            queue.append(cls.root)

print(BinaryTree().InsertNode(4))

would return -> <__main__.Node object at 0x000001A8478CAE60>
```

Comment: `n=BinaryTree().InsertNode(4); print(n.data)`. But only for the first (root) node in your tree.  Or `return cls.root.data`.

Comment: you need to traverse the `cls.root` object to where the `newNode` to be added in else condition

Comment: You *have* returned a `Node` value.  But since that class doesn't have a `__str__` or `__repr__` method, `print` doesn't know how to print it.  So it defaults to simply telling you there's an object at an address.